# Determing whether a case meets two qualifiers when one qualifier requires flexibility in determing whether the match is correct

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have two tables: (1) Lists clinicians and their dates of leave, (2) Lists clinics and the dates the clinics were closed.

I would like to determine how often a clinic is closed due to a clinician's leave time (determined by clinician's leave time falling on the same date).

The tricky part is linking a clinician to their clinics.  The clinics often contain only part of a clinician's name, and the clinics are pretty randomly named.

I have tried to use an if(countif )>0 function with a wildcard(*Clinician*) set-up around the clinician's name to denote if a clinic was closed due to a clinician being gone, but have not been successful.

Thank you in advance for any guidance you are able to provide!

Here is an example of the tables:

[Leave Time versus Clinic Cancellations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guMTT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of a non-VBA way to do this, so I created a function that can no doubt be improved, but I think it gets the results you'd expect given the inputs you provided.

Basically the function will take the range of dates clinics were closed and the names of the clinic (all as a single argument).  The function also takes the Clinician and the Leave Date as separate arguments.  The function will loop through the clinic closures and determine if the clinician in the formula is a partial match for the closed clinic on the date the clinician took leave.

```
Public Function Closed(rngClinic, rngClinician, rngClinicianLeave)
'function loops through each clinic and clinic close date
'to determine if the clinic name contains the clinician who took leave
'on the same date the clinic is closed.
'If so, add this as a closure and continue counting
'until all clinics have been checked.

Dim Clinic() As Variant 'This stores the range of clinic names and dates they were closed
Dim Clinician As String 'just the clinician name on the date of elave
Dim ClinicianLeave As Date ' the leave date of the clinician
Dim iCounter As Integer 'this counts the # of closures given a clinician and a leave date
Dim iClinicCount As Integer 'this is just a count of the # of loops that need to occur



With Excel.Application
    Clinic = .Transpose(rngClinic)
    Clinician = rngClinician
    ClinicianLeave = rngClinicianLeave


iCounter = 0
iClinicCount = .CountA(Clinic) / 2
For x = LBound(Clinic) To iClinicCount
    If Clinic(1, x) = ClinicianLeave And Clinic(2, x) Like "*" & Clinician & "*" Then
        iCounter = iCounter + 1
    End If
Next

End With

Closed = iCounter

End Function
```

Attached are screenshots of the results, both the numbers and formulas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Ryan.  I appreciate your feedback and sharing of your expertise.  Two challenges for me, one, I have not used VBA before, and two, the image descriptions you included are not available to me.  Should a non-VBA user be able to put your code to work?  Can you recommend a simple means of learning how to get started with VBA?

Comment: Hi @user5394861.  The function I provided can be added to a module.  To access your VBA window, try selecting ALT+F11 on your keyboard within Excel.  From the insert menu, select 'Module.'  Within this module, paste the function.  To use this function within your spreadsheet, you need to enter `=Closed(` first, then select the range of dates where your clinics were closed through the last of the clinic names.  Then enter a `,` followed by clinician, another `,` followed by the clinician leave date.  In my example it would look like `=Closed(E2:F10,B2,A2)`.

Comment: I followed your steps and entered =closed(e2:f10,b2,a2) in cell H2.  When I hit enter I got an ambiguous term error.  It appears 'closed' is not being recognized.  Did I neglect a step?  Thanks again, Ryan!

Comment: so you placed the function in a module?  The `closed()` function will work like any other worksheet function, but you need to be sure you're selecting the appropriate ranges.  Based on the screenshot you provided, I'd enter in cell `C2` the following: `=Closed($D$2:$E$10,B2,A2)` because `D2:E2` is your clinic closed dates/name ranges, `B2` is your Clinician name, and `A2` is the clinician leave date.  My example is slightly different because I added an extra column.  From here you can copy the formula in `C2` through `C7`.  This will give a count of closure because of leave.

Comment: I started over on a new workbook and duplicated all of your suggestions onto a fresh spreadsheet.  This time it worked!  You are brilliant, Ryan!  Maybe when I tried it before a running Macro was interfering??  Now I am trying it on real data--744 clinician leave dates, 44416 cancelled clinic dates--the first case(row) is showing #Name? and Calculating(4 Processors) is at 10% five minutes after I inserted your code into the module.  I will let you know how it turns out when calculations finish.

Comment: It took about 50 minutes to run the calculations.  The result was #VALUE! errors--"A value used in the formula is the wrong data type."  The practice data were just names and dates I created.  The real data was from VISTA( CSV converted to Excel) and our VDW.  I had to manipulate the data slightly ( pulled last name from full name, converted dates with hours minutes seconds to just date), but these changes seem unlikely to cause this error.   The range in the closed formula matches what is in the D & E columns.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hoo-Haa!  I shortened my list of cancelled clinic dates to less than 33,000 rows(2 years instead of 4 years), and it worked.  It still took about 45 minutes of calculation time.  Maybe in the future I will run it on a monthly basis.  Thanks again, Ryan!